# Can you pick up an ally's Spiritual Weapon and use it as your own?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, weapons

If an ally summons a *spiritual weapon*, would you be able to grab it and attack with it? And if so, what would the damage and modifiers be?

Comment: Related: [How does the Spiritual Weapon spell work?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/135809/how-does-the-spiritual-weapon-spell-work), [Would it be possible to grab my Spiritual Weapon and make a melee attack with it?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/135439/would-it-be-possible-to-grab-my-spiritual-weapon-and-make-a-melee-attack-with-it)

Answer (score 27):

#### No; the *spiritual weapon* is used by the caster

The text in the spell description is pretty clear on who makes the weapon attack: you (the spell caster).  It is also clear on who causes it to move.

> When you cast the spell, *you* can make *a melee **spell attack*** against a
> creature ... on a hit, the target takes force damage equal to 1d8  plus *your* spell casting bonus ... as a bonus action, on *your* turn, *you* can move the weapon up to 20 feet ....(PHB p. 278)

What happens when the spell is cast is that it creates a magical effect.  If someone else were able to use this weapon as you suggest in your question, they would be making a melee *weapon* attack, or a melee attack, not a melee *spell* attack. (Melee attack, PHB p. 195; spell attack rolls, PHB. p. 205).

Why is it important that this spell specifies a melee spell attack?  Attacks that are *ranged* (as opposed to melee) have disadvantage on when opponents are within 5 feet of you.  (PHB. p. 195 & p. 205).

> A spell is a discrete  magical effect. (PHB, p. 201)

As another clue to the spell's function, the spell is described as being from the *evocation* school, rather than *conjuration* school.   Were a weapon to be created or summoned by this spell, it would most likely have been classified as   conjuration.

> Some conjuration spells create objects or effects out of nothing (PHB p. 203, side bar, Schools of Magic)

Spells in this edition generally do what is in the spell text.  If this magical effect created a weapon that was transferable to another creature,  that would be mentioned in the spell's text.

Compare this to a different spell, like *Goodberry*

> Up to ten berries appear in your hand and are infused with magic for
> the duration.  *A creature can* use its action to eat one berry (PHB, p. 246)

In this case, *a creature* indicates that use of the berries is not restricted to whomever cast the spell.

For another example, see *[Magic Stone](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/magic-stone)*

> You touch one to three pebbles and imbue them with magic. *You or someone else* can make a ranged spell attack with one of the pebbles by throwing it or hurling it with a sling.  (XGtE, p. 160; EE Player Guide, p. 20).

If the [unofficial rulings from J. Crawford are of interest,](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/659845291647070208) he says this:

> A pact weapon is a physical object that someone else can pick up. **A spiritual weapon is a spell effect.**

Comment: Jeremy Crawford has also said explicitly that [spiritual weapons are not physical objects](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/659845291647070208)

Comment: @Rubiksmoose Thx for the link

Answer (score 4):

## No, you can't

If the spell created a usable weapon, the spell's description would say so. It does not.

[*Related question: "Is Spiritual Weapon considered a Spell or a Weapon for Resistance/Immunity purposes?"*](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/89920/is-spiritual-weapon-considered-a-spell-or-a-weapon-for-resistance-immunity-purposes?)