# Would declaring a sworn enemy using an oathbow cause disadvantage when attacking with a spiritual weapon?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, magic-items, weapons, attack

The [*oathbow*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/oathbow) allows you to make the target of its ranged attack your "sworn enemy", which grants a number of benefits to your attacks with the *oathbow* against that enemy. However, it also states:

> While your sworn enemy lives, you have disadvantage on attack rolls
>   with all other weapons.

What happens if you summon a magical weapon, like [*spiritual weapon*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/spiritual-weapon), and try to attack with it while your sworn enemy still lives? Does it not count because it isn't a "capital W" Weapon, or do you get disadvantage on your attacks with it?

Comment: Related: "[Is Spiritual Weapon considered a Spell or a Weapon for Resistance/Immunity purposes?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/89920)"

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### *Spiritual weapon* does not get disadvantage from the *oathbow*'s effect, but other summoned weapons may.

The ["Weapons"](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/equipment#Weapons) portion of the basic rules states:

> Your class grants proficiency in certain weapons, reflecting both the class’s focus and the tools you are most likely to use.

Weapons are tools that characters can gain proficiency in.

The description of the [*spiritual weapon*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/spiritual-weapon) spell states:

> You create a floating, spectral weapon within range that lasts for the duration or until you cast this spell again. When you cast the spell, you can make a **melee spell attack** against a creature within 5 feet of the weapon.

A *spiritual weapon* attack is a melee spell attack (which the *oathbow* does not apply to), not a ranged **weapon** attack or a melee **weapon** attack (which the spell would need to give you proficiency for).

Further adding to this point is the [*shadow blade*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/shadow-blade) spell (XGtE, p. 154), which says:

> It counts as a simple melee weapon with which you are proficient.

*Shadow blade* specifically calls out that it is a simple melee weapon with which you are proficient.
Magical summoned weapons of this type would make attacks at disadvantage due to the *oathbow*'s effects.

Comment: (Confusingly, I don't think "tool" in the quote from the Weapons section is being used in the traditional game sense here, but rather to mean "a thing used in an occupation or pursuit".)

Answer (score 8):

### Ask your GM?

The [*spiritual weapon*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/spiritual-weapon) spell states:

> You create a floating, spectral **weapon** within range that lasts for the duration or until you cast this spell again. When you cast the spell, **you can make** a melee spell attack against a creature within 5 feet of **the weapon.** On a hit, the target takes force damage equal to 1d8 + **your spellcasting ability modifier.**
>
> As a bonus action on your turn, *you can* move **the weapon** up to 20 feet and *repeat the attack* against a creature within 5 feet of it.
>
> **The weapon** can take whatever form you choose [...]

The bolded bits *might* establish that *spiritual weapon* is not only a weapon, but also that *you* (the caster) are the one making the attacks. Thus this would be an attack roll you are making that uses a weapon, even if it is the *spiritual weapon*, so it would have disadvantage.

Note that this is a rather exceptional case since you are making an attack with a weapon but are not actually making a weapon attack. Which...

This honestly makes me unsure of this and I wonder if the spell isn't simply happening to use the word "weapon" without meaning to imply that it is *actually* a weapon. The spell merely *resembles* a weapon without actually *being* one. The following question actually has quite a few answers stating/establishing that *spiritual weapon* is *not* a weapon and I find their points compelling:

- [Is Spiritual Weapon considered a Spell or a Weapon for Resistance/Immunity purposes?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/89920)

Comment: Related (unofficial) Crawford tweet, albeit in a different context: ["A pact weapon is a physical object that someone else can pick up. A spiritual weapon is a spell effect."](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/659845291647070208) I concur with the interpretation in Protonflux's answer to the linked question that cites the spell description - it is not a weapon, just a spell whose effect resembles a weapon.

Comment: @V2Blast It's unquestionably a spell effect, but then the spell seems pretty insistent about calling it a weapon, too. I think the real issue there is that it's a weapon that's being used to make spell attacks (similar to _magic stone_).

Comment: @MarkWells: The pebbles from *magic stone* are definitely not weapons - though they could be hurled with a sling, which is a weapon - qualifying it for features requiring a ranged weapon. However, since it's a ranged spell attack, it doesn't qualify for things requiring a "weapon attack" or "ranged weapon attack".